# python manage.py <commandname> does not work in django 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

def Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.write( "lol" )
```

So I tried creating a custom command in Django 1.8. It is in the directory appname/management/commands/commandname.py . However, trying to run the command using:

```
python manage.py commandname
```

yielded this error:

```
TypeError: Command() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

I've ensured that all the directories contain an __ init__.py file and that the app is added to the project. There doesn't seem to by much info on this online. Please do help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on this doc page
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/), you may want to change that line from `def Command(BaseCommand):` to `class Command(BaseCommand):`.  (it looks like some further changes will be necessary as well)

Comment: Thanks. What a silly silly error. I apologize for taking your time.

Comment: don't mention it, i'm the one poking around SO instead of updating this database schema :P